# Is There SMS Support for BB10 as a web app? and are there alternatives?

Tags: blackberry-webworks, blackberry-10

I was looking for this in their api documentation, only to see BB5-BB7 support it and not BB10. It sounds backwards to me, but let me know if this is still the case or not and if there are workarounds to battle that.

Comment: So is your question whether or not BB10 has support for sending an SMS message from a Web app (ie. Webworks)? Ripple is the Webworks/HTML5 emulator for the BB10 platform.

Comment: I meant the device itself. Is there SMS support for that yet?

Answer (score 1):

SMS is still in the works for BB10 Webworks. There is one possible work around. Though it doesn't allow you to specify a phone number, user would have to write it in manually.

You can use the [**'Share Targets' Example**](https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-WebWorks-Samples/tree/master/ShareTargets). You pass it a string, photo, video, ect. Then it shows the user a list of possible share targets one of those being

[image]

Documentation: http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.invoke.card.html#.invokeTargetPicker

Similar Question/Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15074654/773263